# How to command line compile with Typescript 3.2.2?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I just downloaded and installed the TS v3.2.2 and got a bad surprise: no more tsc.exe !

I'm working on a big .NET project with React and the Build of the web project, where all my *.aspx and react sources are is so lengthy that for quite some time I just:
1) opened the command prompt at the React folder I was working at
2) and run tsc + Enter to compile all the *.ts.

So my question to you is what other options do I have now to run a fast, typescript compile only, of all files inside a specific folder ?

Thanks in advance,
Miguel

Comment: `tsc` should still be included with TypeScript - where did you find an official statement that it isn't?

Comment: Well... first I had a look at the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2 and tsc.exe no longer existed (but it existed in TS 3.1 !).

Comment: Then I got some confirmation at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28761

Comment: Ah, you are using the TypeScript SDK (shipped with Visual Studio), I apologize. I only use the version downloaded from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) (which includes a `tsc` command)

Comment: I also installed locally, on my project folder's node_modules, just to see what files it brings the npm typescript 3.2.2. It also doesn't have the tsc.exe file.

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference on the way to do this, in a windows command prompt, positioning in the specific folder and then just run the command below to compile all *.ts files inside that folder:

```
node "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2\tsc.js"
```

The dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2" is where typescript 3.2.2 was installed.